# Python import module from directory, error reading file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-3.6

***I'm using python 3.7***

**This is my project file structure**

```
.
├── aa
│   ├── reader.py
│   └── readme.txt
└── m.py

1 directory, 3 files
```

*in m.py file:*

```
import aa.reader as reader    
reader.read_file()
```

*in reader.py file:*

```
def read_file():
    with open('readme.txt', 'r') as f:
        d = f.read()
    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(read_file())
```

*in readme.txt file:*

```
this is the content of readme
```

*When I run the m.py file I got this error:*

```
ranick@r-ubt:~/Desktop/kk$ python m.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m.py", line 4, in <module>
    reader.read_file()
  File "/home/ranick/Desktop/kk/aa/reader.py", line 3, in read_file
    with open('readme.txt', 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'readme.txt'
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with relative paths to files in Python, the path is relative to the current working directory (`cwd`), not to the file's current location.

The current working directory is a path from which you are starting your script. In your case, cwd is a folder containing the script `m.py`.

You need to change the path to `readme.txt`. A robust option is to get the path to the script `reader.py` and use it to determine the path to the file `readme.txt`. You can use a module attribute `__file__` to get the module's full file path and then extract the directory name.

*New reader.py*

```py
import os

def read_file():
    readme_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'readme.txt')

    with open(readme_path , 'r') as f:
        d = f.read()

    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(read_file())
```

Answer (score 0):

Filepaths get resolved relative to the path that you called the entry-file `python m.py` from.

To resolve the issue you might either use an absolute path to `readme.txt` or change `'readme.txt'` to `'aa/readme.txt'`.

To find out which absolute path your relative path-ending is applied to you can do the following from `reader.py`:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```